# Gmail bloqueia servidor ao tentar fazer login

Tags: php, google, google-analytics-api

Estou a usar uma api do google analytics em php para mostrar no meu site os dados do analytics. O que acontece, é que ao fazer a autenticação, a google bloqueia o acesso ao servidor. Tive este problema a muito tempo atrás com outro servidor mas já não me lembro como resolvi.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso dar permissão ao servidor na conta google?